# Required get_date oracle sql function replacement in informatica expression transformation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, informatica

I executed below query in oracle sql developer. create_date is number field in oracle.

```
select create_date,get_date(create_date) from test;
```

Output:

```
CREATE_DATE GET_DATE(CREATE_DATE)
801172716   5/22/1995 19:58:36
```

In informatica expression transformation i tried many functions to convert that decimal to date.But i am not able to get the required date.

Can someone tell me which expression should be used in informatica expression transformation.

Comment: `get_date` seems more a user defined function that an Oracle one, so you need to understand the logics behind that function and then try to reply the same logics in informatica.

Answer (score 0):

Your `create_date` numeric value represents a `Unix Timestamp` value. You can use `numtodsinterval` function as

```
select to_timestamp('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
       + numtodsinterval(create_date,'second') as get_datetime
  from test
```

to get the desired value. If you need only the date part, then use :

```
select 
      cast(
       to_timestamp('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
       + numtodsinterval(create_date,'second')
       as date
       ) as get_date
  from test
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5cb4385fe526643a0d48bd7b09850d5)</kbd>

Comment: when i ran the above query select to_timestamp(create_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
       + numtodsinterval(create_date,'second') as get_datetime
  from test; i got the below error in oracle. ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s".. I need the expression in expression transformation in informatica to convert that decimal to timestamp.

Comment: @Rajesh are you sure that create_date is a numeric type field ?

Comment: Yes..It is numeric field. I guess it is some JSON number

Comment: @Rajesh then please convert by `to_number` as `numtodsinterval(to_number(create_date),'second')`, since perhaps it might be percieved as a string even if it contains digits only, because of being extracted from JSON.

Comment: Hi Barbaros: when i run the below query provided by you i am getting correct time but not the date. Can you please provide query for getting the correct date format as well. select numtodsinterval(to_number(create_date),'second') as get_datetime,create_date from test2;
Output: +17939 23:32:45.000000

create_date(FYI): 1550014365
Required Output: 02/12/2019 23:32:45

Comment: Hi @Rajesh. The same logic works. Just replace `create_date` with `to_number(create_date)` for the second query also, e.g. the query that returns `get_date` aliased column.

Comment: Thanks a lot that it worked in Oracle. Now will check whether it works in informatica sql override. Thank you

Comment: It worked in SQL override in informatica as well.. Thanks a lot